# DirectShow-IMediaDet only extracts the first frame

Tags: c++, c, winapi, video, directshow

I experienced a weird effect concerning DirectShow and splitters.
I was not able to track it, so maybe somebody can help?

In my application I extract a few frames from movies.
I do this by DirectShow's IMediaDet interface.
(BTW: It's XP SP3, DirectShow 9.0).

Everything works fine, as long as there is no media splitter involved
(this is the case for mp4, mkv, flv, ...).
Concerning codecs I use the K-Lite distribution.
Since some time there are two splitters: LAV and Haali.
The Gabest splitter has been removed since some time.
But only with the latter activated everything worked fine!

OK - the effect:

It's about IMediaDet.GetBitmapBits:
Some (most) medias that uses splitters always extract the very first frame.
And with some other medias with splitters this effect is only when I
used get_StreamLength before. (Although GetBitmapBits should switch
back to BitmapGrab mode, as the docu says.).
As said - everything works fine as far as no splitter is involved (mpg, wmv, ...).

Does someone experienced a similar effect?

Where may be the bug: In DShow, in the splitters, in my code?

Any help appreciated ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is not quite correct. `IMediaDet::GetBitmapBits` builds a filter graph internally, and attempts to navigate playback to position of interest. Then starts streaming to get a valid image onto its Sample Grabber filter "BitBucket".

It does not matter if splitter is a separate filter or it is combined with source. Important part is the ability of the graph to seek, a faulty filter might be an obstacle there, even though the snapshot is taken. This is the symptom you are describing.

For instance the internal graph might be like this:

[image]

There is a dedicated multiplexer there, and snapshot is taken from correct position.

Comment: By the way, this explains how you can get the snapshots otherwise. When you build the graph yourself, you have way more control over the process, in particular being able to use filters you trust. You don't have this flexibility through `MediaDet`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
If I get you right you think the decoding filter (for AVC1 in my case) might be the cause?
But it doesn't matter which decoder I use (LAV or libavcodec) - both take always only the first frame.
And another thing points to something about the splitter: If I use the Gabest splitter, "it" extracts all the desired positions, with both decoders.

Comment: MediaDet creates a filter graph, you are interested to know what it is exactly - then we can guess why it fails to seek. I don't know why this unknown filter fails to seek in your case.

Comment: Thanks again!
Probably I was hoping for somebody to say: "This is a well known error in DirectShow 9.0/ the splitter xy/ the codec z ..."
As all effects seem to point in that direction.
Well I'll try ... and will state the answer ... if I find one.

Comment: I am pretty sure specific filter is causing this unwanted behavior, but I don't know which one exactly. `MediaDet` is deprecated API and it leaves no control over how internal filter graph is created, so you are at mercy of Intelligent Connect settings. In the same time, I showed you what it is doing and having this in mind you can build a similar graph your self, then grab a video frame, convert to HBITMAP, scale appropriately and you have what `MediaDet` gives to you. And, with controlled graph creation.

Comment: To tell the truth I don't know too much about filter graphs
in DirectShow. I'm just USING the interface in my application.
Up till now I grabbed single frames with the IMediaDet interface.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
This worked fine for everything but streams that are splitted with Haali or LAV splitter. (-> next comment)

Comment: (... continued)
I have been told that maybe not the splitter but the codec may be the problem
(if the use VideoInfoHeader2).
So I tried
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
But this doesn't work either (in buffering mode/ one shot).
In callback mode it works (= walks through all/ different frames).
I would be glad to be pointed to a code example which demonstrates a working
solution for my problem.
Thankyou in advance.